# How can I start screensaver in its own Window (Form,canvas) in Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, screensaver, mirroring

I use software that mirrors my PC to the TV. Works well, but the transfer crashes when transferring screensavers.

One of the screensavers offers the option to start it in its own window - so the mirroring works perfectly. So I'm looking for a way to start the screensaver in its own window (a Form, for example) and then transfer it to the television.

Unfortunately, the first attempt doesn't work; I probably don't get the right handle to the screensaver. Starting with the `"/P"` parameter didn't work, either.

Can someone help me? The OS is "Windows 11".

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
   Shift: TShiftState);
var
   hMyApp: hwnd; //Handle auf das Window welches man im Form braucht
   vWinHnd: hwnd;
   VExePfad: string;
   vParam: string;
begin
   if Key = ord(32) then
   begin
      try
         vWinHnd := Form1.Handle;
         vParam := '/P ' + inttostr(vWinHnd) ;
         vExePfad := 'C:\Windows\System32\Bubbles.scr';
         ShellExecute(0,
            nil,
            PChar(vExePfad),
            //PChar(vParam),
            nil,
            nil,
            SW_MINIMIZE );
            application.ProcessMessages;
         hMyApp := GetwindowDc(0);
         form1.Caption := 'Handle ' + inttostr(hMyApp);
         Windows.SetParent(hMyApp, vWinHnd); //Parent mit Windows.SetParent
         ShowWindow(hMyApp, SW_MAXIMIZE);
      finally
         Releasedc(0, hMyApp);
      end;
   end;

   if Key = ord(27) then
   begin
      Application.Terminate;
   end;
end;
```

---

**UPDATE**

I now tried the following (without `SetParent` and `ShowWindow`, using `"/P"` and `"/p"`), but that didn't work either:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
var
   hMyApp: hwnd; //Handle auf das Window welches man im Form braucht
   vWinHnd: hwnd;
   VExePfad: string;
   vParam: string;
begin
   if Key = ord(32) then
   begin
      try
         vWinHnd := self.Handle;
         vParam := '/p ' + inttostr(vWinHnd) ;
         vExePfad := 'C:\Windows\System32\Bubbles.scr';
         ShellExecute(0,
            'open',
            PChar(vExePfad),
            PChar(vParam),
            nil,
            SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
         //application.ProcessMessages;
         //hMyApp := GetForegroundWindow();
         //Windows.SetParent(vWinHnd,hMyApp ); //Parent mit Windows.SetParent
         form1.Caption := vParam;
         //ShowWindow(hMyApp, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED  );
      finally
        // Releasedc(0, hMyApp);
      end;
   end;
   if Key = ord(27) then
   begin
      Application.Terminate;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: `Form1.Handle` should be `Self.Handle`, also try `/p` instead of `/P` in case the screensaver is case-sensitive. But more importantly, `GetWindowDC()` returns an `HDC` not an `HWND`, so your `hMyApp` is invalid for `SetParent()` and `ShowWindow()` (and you can't maximize a child window anyway). You probably meant to use `GetForegroundWindow()` instead. However, you DO NOT need to call `SetParent()` or `ShowWindow()` to begin with as the screensaver itself is responsible for displaying its own UI inside of the parent `HWND` you specify in `/p`. DO NOT reparent the screensaver UI yourself.

Comment: I tried it as I understood you (see above), it didn't work either - what's wrong?

Comment: Define "doesn't work" exactly. Be specific

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy; The saver still starts in full screen, not within the form as planned.

Comment: The screensaver is the bubble saver that comes with Windows and the preview also works in the screensaver settings dialog.
Changing "/p" to "/p:..." made no difference. Unfortunately, I don't know how to call the saver with "CreateProcess", I don't understand the parameters, sorry.

Comment: Something like this: `var SI: TStartupInfo; PI: TProcessInformation; ... ZeroMemory(@SI, SizeOf(SI)); SI.cb := SizeOf(SI); SI.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW; SI.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED; if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(vExePfad + ' ' + vParam), nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, SI, PI) then begin CloseHandle(PI.hThread); CloseHandle(PI.hProcess); end;`

Comment: Your latest edit should be posted as an answer instead. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remy Lebeau said the answer in a comment:

> Then the screensaver is likely not implemented correctly, as all screensavers are expected to handle the `/p` parameter for displaying a preview in the OS's own configuration screen. The only other things I can suggest is 1) try using `'/p:<hwnd>'` instead of `'/p <hwnd>'`, and 2) try using `CreateProcess()` instead of `ShellExecute()`.

Here is the code that works thanks to him.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
   Shift: TShiftState);
var
   vWinHnd: hwnd;
   VExePfad: string;
   vParam: string;
   SI: TStartupInfo;
   PI: TProcessInformation;
begin
   if Key = ord(32) then
   begin
      try
         vWinHnd := self.Handle;
         vParam := '/p ' + inttostr(vWinHnd);
         vExePfad := 'C:\Windows\System32\Bubbles.scr';
         ZeroMemory(@SI, SizeOf(SI));
         SI.cb := SizeOf(SI);
         SI.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
         SI.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED;
         if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(vExePfad + ' ' + vParam),
            nil,
            nil,
            False,
            0,
            nil,
            nil,
            SI,
            PI) then
         begin
            CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
            CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
         end;
      finally
         Form1.FormStyle := fsNormal;
      end;
   end;

   if Key = ord(27) then
   begin
      Application.Terminate;
   end;
end;
end.
```